# Program to print the input number is equal or not goes wrong

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, dosbox

So the problem is DosBox shows this pattern...

[image]

Input given by me=8
that is not equal=3 but it show no is equal. How????
And what does this pattern mean?

```
.MODEL SMALL
.stack 100h

.data

msg1 db 'no is equal $'
msg2 db 'no is not equal $'

.code

main proc

mov ax,@data
mov dx,ax

mov dl,'3'
mov ah,1
int 21h

cmp al,dl
je j2

mov dx,offset msg2
mov ah,9
int 21h

Mov ah,4ch
int 21H

j2:

mov dx,offset msg1
mov ah,9
int 21h

Mov ah,4ch
int 21H

MAIN ENDP  

END MAIN
```

Comment: Change `mov dx,ax` to `mov ds,ax`. `DX` and `DS` are different things ;-)

Comment: problem is solved mov ax, @data
mov ds, ax